# Use keyboard and jQuery $(document).keypress() on touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

My page needs keyboard control even on touch devices. I put a BUTTON element that focuses an INPUT element. That works, the sofkeyboard shows up.

```
$('button').click(function() {
  $(this).next().focus();
});
```

But the $(document).keypress() will not be fired on Chrome for Android as long as the INPUT element has the focus.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  var char = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  $('body').append(char);
});
```

I could track the events on the INPUT element, but then I have double inputs on many devices.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is creating INPUT elements and binding functions on the "input" events of the INPUT elements. They store most of the inputs. To make sure not to have double inputs from both "keyup" and "input", the "keyup" event will only be used when the INPUT element does not have focus.